# Remove default input styling in Materialize

Tags: css, materialize

I want to remove input styling in Materialize. Like Jquerymobile, I can remove the styling with `data-role="none"`, how to do it in Materialize. I want to make a simple search box, but I am troubled by default styling.

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for input text :

```
<style type="text/css">

  .MyDiv input[type=text]:not(.browser-default){
    padding: 1% 6%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border:1px solid #BEBEBE;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;  
    height: 33px;
}

.MyDiv input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]){
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
    border: 1px solid #88D5E9;
}
</style>


<div class="MyDiv">
    <input type="text" name="username">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the default form style in Materialize just add this to you class "browser-default"